# line isn't visible due to other components on the frame

Tags: image, line, frame, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm trying to draw a line on my frame (did it on FormPaint method).

The issue is that frame have some components on it, and among all it have image which covers all frame's area.

Therefore, the line isn't visible.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing on the Frame itself, but the TImage is covering the Frame's client area, so it covers any drawing that you do on the Frame.  You need to re-think your drawing strategy.  If you want the line to appear on top of the TImage, then draw the line on the TImage instead of the Frame.  Or else put a separate TImage/TPaintBox on top of the TImage and draw on that instead.